# Distribution of a second degree polynomial of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function, polynomial

I would like to compute 
$$P(Y=aX^2+bX+c<0)$$

where $X \sim N(0,\sigma)$. I can do it quite easily using Monte Carlo. However, I've been asked to find the analytical pdf $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$ and then compute

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^0 f_Y(y) dy$$

I guess $f_Y(y)$ will be such that $I$ can only be computed numerically. However, since it's a univariate integral, numerical methods are available to compute it to very high accuracy. Is there a (relatively simple) expression for $f_Y(y)$, so that I can perform numerical integration? Or is there another possibility for computing $I$, apart from Monte Carlo (which is in my opinion the most sensible approach)?

Comment: Do you _have_ to find the pdf of $Y$ first and then integrate it over the negative real line, or can you use the method pointed out by mpiktas which avoids finding the pdf of $Y$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, thanks for the question. I was specifically requested to 1. find $f_Y(y)$ and 2. integrate over $[-\infty,0]$. So, an answer which does exactly that would be great. On the other hand, I can point out that the request is unreasonable and that I have already two very nice methods (MC and @mpiktas) which work fine. Thus, the answer to your question is: I don't strictly _have to_ (I'm not getting fired if I don't), but I sure would appreciate being able to do it (thus avoiding yet another discussion with the requestor).

Comment: OK here goes. Note that $F_Y(y) = P\{Y \leq y\} = P\{aX^2+bX+c-y \leq 0\}$ which can be expressed in terms of the standard Gaussian CDF $\Phi(\cdot)$ using the method described in @mpkitas's answer. Taking the derivative w.r.t, $y$ will then give the pdf $f_Y(y)$. Also, tell your requestor that you don't actually need to_explicitly_ integrate the pdf to find $I$ since $I = F_Y(0)$ whose value you have already determined.

Comment: @DilipSarwate fantastic! In other words, $x_1$ and $x_2$ in mpkitas 's answer become functions of $y$, and then I just apply the chain rule for derivation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are roots of the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$. We must assume that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are real and non-equal, otherwise the probability in question is trivially zero or one.

We have two cases.

1. $a>0$, then $P(aX^2+bX+c<0) = P(x_1<X<x_2)$.
2. $a<0$, then $P(aX^2+bX+c<0) = P(X<x_1 \cup X>x_2)=1- P(x_1<X<x_2).$

Since $X$ is normal, the probabilities can be calculated using the cumulative distribution function of normal variable.

Comment: excellent! And of course we have analytical expressions for $x_1$ and $x_2$ (roots of a quadratic equation), so it's all very simple. Thanks! PS of course $x_1$ and $x_2$ are always real and distinct in my case. I forgot to specify that.

Comment: Very clever solution. I was about to suggest deriving the distribution of $Y$ but totally unnecessary. Well done!

Comment: @JohnA.Ramey See the comments on the main question.